# view field. It looks like a function needs 1 more argument

Tags: elm

I have a problem in the view I would like display the model so i am using the code:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)


main =
  beginnerProgram { model = model, update = update, view = view }


type alias Model = {
    toto : String
  }


model = { toto = "" }



type Msg = UpdateText String


update msg model =
  case msg of
    UpdateText text ->
      {model | toto = text }




view : Model -> Html (String -> Msg) 
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick UpdateText ,value "hello" ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model.toto) ]
    , button [ onClick UpdateText, value "word" ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

I have this error but i don't understand what is not good in my view :

> The argument to function `beginnerProgram` is causing a mismatch.
>
> 11|   beginnerProgram { model = model, update = update, view = view }
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Function `beginnerProgram` is expecting the argument to be:
>
> ```
> { ..., view : { toto : String } -> Html (Msg) }
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> { ..., view : Model -> Html (String -> Msg) }
> ```
>
> Hint: Problem in the `view` field. It looks like a function needs 1
>   more argument.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdateText` accepts a single argument and returns `Msg` value. Your view buttons should look something like this:

```
button [ onClick (UpdateText "hello") ] [ text "-" ]
```